# Base interface in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I need some sort of way to mark base interfaces and identify if a class implemented the base interface or its derived interface. c# doesn't allow having 'abstract interface'. Is there any way to do this in c#?

```
public interface IBaseFoo
{
     void BaseMethod();
}

public interface IFoo : IBaseFoo
{
     void FooMethod();
}

public class Base
{

}

public class A : Base, IFoo
{

}

public class B : Base, IBaseFoo
{

}
```

Now in the following method I need to check if the `typeCls` is implemented the `IFoo` or `IBaseFoo` without explicitly specifying types. I need sort of a way to mark the base interface and identify it in the method. (ie: if c# allowed having abstract interface, I could have check if `IsAbstract` property of interfaces of `typeClas`)

```
public bool IsBaseFooImplemented<T>(T typeCls) where T : Base
{
     // Here I need to check if the typeCls is implemented the IFoo or IBaseFoo
}
```

Comment: This smells a little bit. You say you "need" to check this - why do you need to check? What is it you're trying to achieve that you think standard SOLID OO won't give you? Because you're about to break open/closed, so think carefully before you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `IFoo : IBaseFoo`, every class implementing `IFoo` also implements `IBaseFoo`. But not the other way around, so you can simply check whether `typeCls is IFoo`.

Do note that changing behavior based on implemented interfaces generally is a design smell that bypasses the use for interfaces in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
//somewhere define 

static List<IBaseFoo> list = new List<IBaseFoo>();

public class A : Base, IFoo
{
    public A()
    {
        YourClass.list.add(this);
    }
}

public class B : Base, IBaseFoo
{
    public B()
    {
        YourClass.list.add(this);
    }
}
```

//then you can check if a class is IFoo or not.

```
public bool IsBaseFooImplemented<T>(T typeCls) where T : Base
{
     foreach(var c in list )
     {
         if(typeof(c) == typeCls) return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

I have not tested the code but it should work.